# Coding image processing tools properly

Tags: java, user-interface, image-processing

We are doing an image processing project in Java. The UI offers tools like: rectangle selection and magic wand tool.

For now,
There is a class:
**ImageView** :

```
/*Other classes can set image, this class will draw the image*/
public class ImageView extends JPanel{

/*It resizes the image to fit the panel and draws the image on the panel.*/
public void setImage(BufferedImage image){/*code*/}
```

}

Each tool is treated as a separated class, extending **ImageView**.
For example:
**Rectangle Selection tool:**

```
/*It has a function which allows the user to draw rectangle around the image, I am    not going to write the code here because it is long and unnecessary*/
public class ResizableRectangleView extends ImageView {

/*It returns the rectangle drawn by the user*/
public Rectangle getRectange(){return rectangle;}
```

}

Another class **UIController** creates the "tool" based on which tool the user has selected. Then that JPanel (tool or view)  (for example: ResizableRectangleView or some other view) is diplayed in the GUI. The user can then draw rectangle (in case of ResizableRectangleView).

For each tool, there would be a separate class. And whenever the user selects the tool, a new object is created, an image is provided to that tool and then the tool(view) is added to the UI.

I don't like this approach. My question is, how do programs like Gimp and Photoshop allow multiple tools to be used on same image/layer? How should I proceed?

A block diagram with components (showing flow of data and commands) would be really appreciated.

Comment: Would the [command patter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) be used here?  (Not rhetorical, I really don't know.)

Comment: I am reading about command pattern now. I do not what it is.

Comment: Yes, it kind of follows command pattern. In fact, the UI we are making is like a wizard. Each window asks for certain image processing tools to be used, then the user clicks next (and so on) and finally the result is shown. A class "Engine" stores the necessary data and functions so that the application can proceed in a sequence. All the windows access and store data in "Engine" and execute the functions provided by "Engine".